# SQL Server CE 4.0 and frequent corrupted memory crash

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sql-server-ce

I have a WPF application that uses SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 for storing data on the local machine. I am experiencing random but fairly frequent crashes from the Compact Edition 4.0 database. It always gives the same error....

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other 
memory is corrupt.
```

...with the following limited stack trace...

```
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethodsHelper.SafeRelease(IntPtr& ppUnknown)
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ReleaseNativeInterfaces()
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.Finalize()
```

I have a separate thread that I use for all CE database calls so I know that all my database calls are serialized (there are no concurrent calls to the database), and they all occur on the same thread. When the exception occurs it always has the details above.

It is not reproducible but it happens often enough that my application never survives more than 10 minutes of operation. Sometimes it will crash in the first few seconds and sometimes as much as 10 minutes into operation but most likely somewhere between the two extremes.

I cannot find anything useful from Googling and so hope that this is an issue that others might have seen and have a workaround for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much experimentation I found that wrapping the database calls inside a transaction solved the problem. So instead of the original code like this...

```
using (AMSDBContext context = CreateDatabaseContext())
{
    // actual operation code called here...

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I now do the following and it has not crashed since...

```
using (AMSDBContext context = CreateDatabaseContext())
{
    if (context.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        context.Connection.Open();

    EntityConnection entityConnection = (EntityConnection)context.Connection;
    using (EntityTransaction tx = entityConnection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // actual operation code called here...

        context.SaveChanges();
        tx.Commit();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

SqlCeConnection and releated objects cannot be shared across threads, and this is probably what you are facing. Create a new object per thread.

Comment: I was already doing exactly that. I came up with a solution, or more of a workaround because I do not know why it solves the problem, in the answer I have now added.